# Python 3.7.2 | How to define the writer.writerow part in the coding?

Tags: python, csv, nameerror

I am a begineer in Python and also this site. Right now, I've been hooked up in this bug since last 4 days

It says "NameError: name 'name' is not defined"

The code that I wrote is -

```
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

def get_length(file_path):
    with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        reader_list = list(reader)
        print(reader_list)
        return len(reader_list)

def append_data(file_path, name, email):
    fieldnames = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'amount', 'sent']
    # number of rows?
    next_id = get_length(file_path)
    with open(file_path, "a", newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        #writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({
                "id": next_id,
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
                "amount": "1293.32",
                "sent": "",
            })

#append_data("data.csv", "Star", "lolme@gmail.com")

filename = "data.csv"
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
with open(filename, "r") as csvfile, temp_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'amount', 'sent']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    #writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        writer.writerow({
                "id": row["id"],
                "name": row[name],
                "email": row[email],
                "amount": "1292.23",
                "sent": "",

            })
```

**And the output is as follows - **

```
OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'Star'), ('email', 'lolme@gmail.com'), ('amount', '1293.32'), ('sent', '')])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

What should I do now?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Pay closer attention to the difference between `row["id"]` (which works), and `row[name]` (which doesn't).

Comment: @jasonharper is correct, you need to replace both row[name] to row["name"] and also the email